# Error: '[1]', hexadecimal value 0x02, is an invalid character - DocumentFormat.OpenXml

Tags: c#, .net

I'm working with the DocumentFormat.OpenXml library with version: 2.9.1 ,in C# to generate Excel files from DataTables. I have encountered an issue where I'm getting the following error:

```
Error: '[1]', hexadecimal value 0x02, is an invalid character.
```

Here is the code snippet:

```
public TestMethod()
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            using (var workbook = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(ms, DocumentFormat.OpenXml.SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new Sheets();
                AddStyleSheet(workbook);
                uint sheetId = 1;
                foreach (DataTable table in ds.Tables)
                {
                    var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                    var sheetData = new SheetData();
                    sheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet();
                    Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();
                    string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);
                    if (sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Count() > 0)
                    {
                        sheetId = sheets.Elements<Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
                    }

                    Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
                    {Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = reportNames?.FirstOrDefault() ?? "Report"};
                    sheets.Append(sheet);
                    Row headerRow = new Row();
                    List<String> columns = new List<string>();
                    foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
                    {
                        columns.Add(column.ColumnName);
                        Cell cell = new Cell();
                        cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                        cell.StyleIndex = 1;
                        cell.CellValue = new CellValue(column.ColumnName);
                        headerRow.AppendChild(cell);
                    }

                    sheetData.AppendChild(headerRow);
                    foreach (DataRow dsrow in table.Rows)
                    {
                        Row newRow = new Row();
                        foreach (String col in columns)
                        {
                            Cell cell = new Cell{StyleIndex = 0};
                            cell.StyleIndex = 2;
                            cell.DataType = CellValues.String;
                            cell.CellValue = new CellValue(dsrow[col]?.ToString()); 
                            newRow.AppendChild(cell);
                        }

                        sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
                    }

                    var columnSizeUpdate = ColumnSizeUpdate(sheetData, columnsWidthToUpdate);
                    sheetPart.Worksheet.InsertAt(columnSizeUpdate, 0);
                    sheetPart.Worksheet.AppendChild(sheetData);
                }

                workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Save();
                workbook.Close();
                fileStream = ms.ToArray();
            }
        }
    }
```

The error seems to be related to the dsrow[col]?.ToString() line. I suspect that there might be a character in the data that is causing this issue, but I'm not sure how to identify and handle it.

Could someone please help me understand what might be causing this error and how to resolve it? Additionally, if there's a way to identify and handle invalid characters in the data gracefully, that would be greatly appreciated.

Can anyone please help me here by providing their guidance